# How to make the underline came after the second line in mobile view?

Tags: html, css, sass

I have implemented a code for blue underline for company name, but when it's in the mobile view blue line appears in the first line. How can I make that start appear in the second line?

My CSS code

```
 label {
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: $text-default-color;
  margin-right: 25px;

  @media #{$sm-and-less} {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }

  &:after {
    @extend %nav-underline;
    @extend %ease;
  }
```

Output image
[image: Output image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```css
label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

label::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: blue;
 }
```

```html
<label>
  On one line Lorem ispum dolor sit amed
</label>

<label style="width: 100px;">
  On two lines Lorem ispum
</label>
```